# Should I close a master question in favor of one of its duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

Should I close a question that is the master of already closed duplicates in favor of a more recent question that has better answers?

Until now I generally closed questions as duplicates only in favor of older questions. But now I notice that some of those questions have better answers than the master question.

So should I revert my decision and make the one with the poorer but older answers the duplicate of the one with the better but more recent answers?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Any reason you're not merging them instead?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/

Comment: Hm, I haven’t thought of that yet.